# Using trigger.io with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, trigger.io

I want to try using trigger.io.

We have a Web App and using GAE.
How can we test our Web App with trigger.io?
I see that on the "WEB" section of the toolkit there's only a spot for "Heroku".
Is it possible?
Do we need to migrate?
How can i test our web app with android? I couldn't find a place to direct it to our index.html.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The web section in the Toolkit basically lets you deploy your mobile app as a mobile website, based on Node.js.

If you have an existing web app that you'd like to use as the backend for a mobile app, then it's a case of exposing some sort of HTTP API which your mobile app then interacts with.

Having the mobile app just receive JSON from GAE, build its HTML views and present them to the user works really well.

Comment: I am still confused by this.  When I attempt to view index.html, I get 'forge is not defined'.  Somehow this is injected when using iOS/Android/node.js.  How can I circumvent this issue?